# ReactJS : this.setState is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am new to ReactJS and I am having an error "this.setState is not a function".

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        visible: false,
        navLinesShow: true
    };

    this.navOpen = this.navOpen.bind(this)

}

navOpen() {
    this.setState({
        navStatus: "navShow",
        navLinesShow: false
    });

    if ( this.state.visible === false) {

        setTimeout(function (){

            this.setState({
                visible: true
             });

        }, 3000);

    }
```

I have added this.navOpen = this.navOpen.bind(this) to the contructor. So I guess the problem is with setTimeout function.

What is a possible fix?

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the problem is the setTimeout inside the setTimeout function "this" refer to the function itself: so the solution is the typical `var that = this` :

```
navOpen() {
this.setState({
    navStatus: "navShow",
    navLinesShow: false
});
if ( this.state.visible === false) {
 var that = this;
    setTimeout(function (){
        that.setState({
            visible: true
         });
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Hello Pinturic. Yes, this works perfectly. Maybe You could explain this for me to get a better understanding?

Comment: You can also use arrow function: `setTimeout( _ => { this.setState(...) }, 3000)` to get `this` work as expected

Comment: I updated the solution if it is not clear I will detail it. And @pawel is right if your browsers/transpilers support it you can use fat arrow syntax

Comment: Without transpilation / ES6 support you can avoid `that = this` using bind: `setTimeout(function(){ ... }.bind(this), 3000)` :)

Comment: Pawel I guess the .bind(this) will work best for me at the moment! thanx

Answer (score 3):

It is because `this` doesn't have the correct value due to runtime binding. You need to use lexical binding. The best solution is to use `ES6` arrow functions `() => {}` which provides lexical binding of this value. Even with the `setTimeout()` the lexical binding of this would fix the error you are getting

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        visible: false,
        navLinesShow: true
    };
}

navOpen = () => {
    this.setState({
        navStatus: "navShow",
        navLinesShow: false
    });

    if ( this.state.visible === false) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                visible: true
             });
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution in addition to @pinturic's solution is to use ES6 arrow functions.  If you're using ES6/Babel, etc., you can use an arrow function to bind to the lexical `this`.

```
navOpen() {
    this.setState({
        navStatus: "navShow",
        navLinesShow: false
    });
    if (!this.state.visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({visible: true}), 3000);
    }
}
```